# Como formatar palavras que não estão em dicionários?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, norma-culta

Em textos formais -- como leis, contratos e provas --, não seria possível "inventar" uma palavra; se eu estiver escrevendo para um amigo, por exemplo, eu posso escrever qualquer coisa. Porém, com tudo, todavia, se eu estiver escrevendo um poema, um livro não tão formal ou afins e eu tiver que publicar e quiser usar uma palavra que não exista em dicionários, como eu devo fazer?

Ex.:

"""
Sim, eu sei; por isso o que eu disse é gabrielino.

Mas, ainda assim, pretendo ser mais velhor contigo."""

A palavra "gabrielino", pelo que eu sei, está correta e deve ser tratada como uma palavra normal, mesmo não estando em dicionários, pois segue a morfologia: "Gabriel" + "-ino"; porém posso estar errado.

A palavra "velhor" não existe em dicionário, e segue o final "-or" em "melhor", "pior", "maior" e "menor". Assim, "velhor" = "mais velho"; ex.: "o velhor texto grego foi entregue à Biblioteca Nacional", "os velhores da família se safaram do Corona', pelo menos" e "eu estou velhor, cada dia". Sendo *-or* vindo de *melh**or***, *pi**or***, *mai**or*** e *men**or***, *velhor* seria falado como *velhór*:

"""

#### Ve·lhor |ó|

(*velho* + *-or*)

adjetivo

1. Comparativo de superioridade de *velho*; mais velho.

advérbio

1. Comparativo de superioridade de *velho*; mais velho.
2. De modo mais velho; mais velho.

nome masculino

1. O mais velho.

nome de dois gêneros

1. Pessoa que é considerada mais velha que as outras

""" Baseei-me em da definição de "melhor" do Priberam.

Sendo assim, devo escrever "velhor" em itálico ou tratar como uma palavra normal? Devo informar seu significado prò leitor?

Comment: No Livro Laranja Mecânica há várias gírias (ou palavras que não existem no dicionário). Elas são escritas em itálico e o significado está num apêndice. Acho q se não tem apêndice, deve colocar um asterisco e explicar o significado

Comment: Não, o escritor inventa, o leitor se vira.

Comment: Isso fica a seu critério, em um texto técnico onde possivelmente o autor cria conceitos é adequado explicitar cada significado. Em um texto literário o autor tem maior "licença poética" para "brincar" livremente com a linguagem. Cabe notar que o uso demasiado de neologismos ou termos fabricados pode ser irritante ao leitor, cabe usá-las quando seu significado pode ser inferido ou facilmente interpretável.

Comment: @Edney, concordo. Por isso eu tentei apenas usar o final "-or", que existe noutras palavras.